# View loading slow if done inside -alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a loadView method which loads an empty view

```
- (void) loadView {
    UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

If I run it from viewDidLoad of PresentingVC, it runs fast.

But if I run like

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   [self loadView]
}
```

It takes time.

Would you the reason?

I even tried running on main thread. But no use. There was no other thread running anyways/

**EDIT**

It works as suggested by Gary below

Comment: Can you define "slow". Have you tried changing your alert view delegate method to be: `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your alert view delegate method to be: - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex